# Forms based authentication error on log out

Tags: sharepoint-server, forms-authentication

I have configured Forms based authentication and I can login with Windows authentication but when I log out I get following error:

> "Claim identity is not from a trusted login provider. Identity Name
>   '0#.w|alidev\spwebapp'."

Alidev is my DC and "*spwebapp*" is account running app pool.

Comment: any help please?